# Is Boruto published in Weekly Shonen Jump?

Tags: naruto

Is *Boruto* published in *Weekly Shonen Jump*? It seems to come out monthly but it was on the cover of and in *Weekly Shonen Jump* recently.

Source: [Weekly Shonen Jump Rankings - Crunchyroll forum](http://www.crunchyroll.com/forumtopic-809337/weekly-shonen-jump-rankings?pg=115) (find for "Boruto" keyword)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, *Boruto* is serialized in *Weekly Shonen Jump* and yes, it is published monthly, despite being in a weekly magazine. [ANN article on it.](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2016-03-14/naruto-spinoff-manga-boruto-launches-on-may-9/.99797)